MASM Int 16.1 Exception: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
I'm writing a basic game in MASM , targeting x64. In the below code, I call INT 16.1 to get input from keyboard. However, when running the app to test for keyboard input, the app crashes. When running the app in the VS Debugger, the INT 16 call produces the following error:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF73D0D176F in AssemblyGame.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

I've pasted the code that produces the error below
_GameLoop PROC
    call _GameInput

    mov rax, 0h
    ret
_GameLoop ENDP

_GameInput PROC
    ; Check if any key is being pressed
    mov ah, 01h
    int 16h  ;; <--- This is the line where the error is produced
    call DebugPrint
    jz NO_KEY_PRESSED
    
    ; Check which key is being pressed (AL contains ascii character)
    mov ah, 00h
    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h

    ; Check W key
    cmp al, 77h     ; Lowercase w
    je W_KEY_PRESSED

    cmp al, 57h     ; Uppercase W
    je W_KEY_PRESSED
...

Edit: The comment below mentions a post with a similar issue. Apparently, INT operations are how MS-DOS exposed its API, but modern Windows does not support these operations for exposing the API. If I find a better way to access keyboard input, I'll leave another edit with my solution.

Similar: Why does using "int 21h" on Assembly x86 MASM cause my program to crash?. Of course, you're trying to invoke interrupt 16h instead of 21h, and on 64-bit windows instead of 32-bit windows, but the reason why that doesn't work is the same.

Thanks for sharing this! I guess it makes sense that modern Windows blocks that kind of operation. I really appreciate you responding!

Windows has various ways of getting keyboard input, such as reading keyboard state directly (for example GetKeyboardState or DI GetDeviceState) or by letting windows tell you about the key instead of asking (process WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP events in your event loop)
